react and tailwind with @chakra-ui
Is anyone here familiar with @chakra-ui? I've bought a code from HORIZON UI, and I don't know how to extract each component's code from it. The code is written in React JSX and Tailwind CSS. Can anyone assist me in understanding the code and how to do it just once? Please, I need help.

Why do you need to extract the code from the components? ChakraUI provides pre-developed components that are ready to use. The only aspects you might need to adjust are the behavior or presentation, which can be done through props.
Similarly, for components developed with Tailwind, you can refer to the component's styles on the documentation page: https://horizon-ui.com/docs-tailwind/docs/react/modal. Then, simply copy the code from the documentation, adapt it to your project, and voilà!

Thanks Mario!
The problem is that, as I mentioned, I bought all the components from Horizon UI and the way they arrange their code and pages wasn't very clear, that's why...
